# How to lock a cell?

Tags: excel, vba

How to lock a cell using VBA?
I saw to lock cells you need protect the sheet, but it lock all cells
I want lock 1 cell
my code

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    If Environ$("computername") = "09-PC-0154" Then PCdeposito = "F:" Else PCdeposito = "\\09-PC-0154"
    Ruta = Me.Path
    If Me.Name = Form62 Then
        Worksheets("Hoja1").bNuevo.Enabled = True
        Worksheets("Hoja1").Vale.Enabled = True
        Limpiar
    Else
        Worksheets("Hoja1").bNuevo.Enabled = False
        Worksheets("Hoja1").Vale.Enabled = False
        Worksheets("Hoja1").Range("H2").Locked = True
        NombreAnterior = Worksheets("Hoja1").Range("E11").Value
        Worksheets("Hoja1").Protect
    End If
    LeerArchivoFichas
    LeerArchivoAgentes
    LeerArchivoLegajos
    Worksheets("Hoja1").Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Idea is ask if Im opening a new book or an existing numered book

Anyway the relevant for this question is the Else part

I want lock cell H2 then lock it and next line protect the sheet

But then code stop with error as with protected sheet, later lines after the IF cant work (as those functions need write at other cells)

And if no protect the sheet, the line Worksheets("Hoja1").Range("H2").Locked = True has no effect and I can write at H2

(Also I suspect if protect the sheet, users cant write at other cells)

Comment: The default cells status for `Locked` property is `True`. Please, use  `Worksheets("Hoja1").Cells.Locked = False`, before  `Worksheets("Hoja1").Range("H2").Locked = True`...

Comment: Worksheets("Hoja1").Cells.Locked = False say error. Im at spanish version of Excel and say "No se puede asignar la propiedad Locked de la clase Range" (Cant assign property Locked of the class Range)

Comment: Is the sheet in discussion already protected? If so, you need to unprotect it, of course...

Comment: Now work. Need unprotect sheet before change cells properties. For now at start of my code use Worksheets("Hoja1").Unprotect then if enter at the else and after the Locked lines use Worksheets("Hoja1").Protect

Comment: That's correct...

Answer (score 0):

A cells 'locked' status **does absolutely nothing** - *until the sheet is protected*.

By default, all cells are locked - but without protecting the sheet those locks are useless.

But, when you protect a sheet, those locks take effect - meaning you're unable to alter those cells.

So if you unlock a cell, before protecting a sheet - just that cell is editable after protection is applied.

So if you want to lock just one cell, the most straight-forward method is:

- remove sheet protection
- unlock all the sheet's cells
- lock the cell that you want protected
- apply sheet protection

You can also dictate whether locked cells, unlocked cells or both can be selected - when applying your sheet protection.